# Как вставить разрыв страницы (переход на новую строчку) в ячейке HTML таблицы

Tags: html, css, haml

Делаю вывод html страницы в RubyOnRails проекте и столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть ячейка таблицы в которую я вывожу строку, например "значение1, значение2, значение3". Эта строка подстраивается под ширину окна браузера. Но мне нужен такой вывод: "значени1 новая строка, значение2 новая строка, значение3 новая строка". Есть идеи как это сделать?

Comment: Было бы лучше если бы код и/или картинку привели с желаемым результатом и неверным. Строку разбивать на новую, в пределах ячейки или в таблице по новой строке со своей ячейкой? Вроде и вопрос кажется простым, но что-то не совсем ясно, что надо)

Comment: Извините, если не правильно выразился. Таблица уже разбита на ячейки. Нужно вставить разрыв страницы в одной ячейке. Т.е. у меня сейчас есть такая ячейка, в которую я вывожу такую строку: "значение1 значение2 и т.д". Так вот нужно вставить разрывы страницы внутри этой строки когда мне нужно. Т.е. не нужно писать логику для вставки этих разрывов. Я сам вручную их вставлю в ячейку, но я не знаю как.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу кусочек кода из шаблона haml

```
%tr
  %td Id: #{result.id} Likes: #{result.likes} Author name: #{result.name}
```

Как видите, у меня на выводе будет длинная строка и нужно ее немного отформатировать. А именно вставить переход на новую строку перед: Likes, Author name и так далее.